# How do I configure nginx to just deliver whatever it finds at the configured url

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I start a nginx reverse proxy in docker-compose.
The first docker compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  rproxy:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - '/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt'
    networks:
      - main
networks:
  main:
    name: main_network
```

The dockerfile just makes sure the nginx server has the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name website.dev;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.dev/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.dev/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        resolver 127.0.0.11;
        set $frontend http://website;
        proxy_pass $frontend;
    }
}
```

First I run this following docker-compose file. Then when I try to access www.website.dev i get a 502 error *as expected*.

Then I run this other docker-compose file defined below:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  website:
    image: registry.website.dev/frontendcontainer:latest
    command: npm run deploy
    networks:
      main:
        aliases: 
          - website
networks:
  main:
    external:
      name: main_network
```

This should start the website container on the same network as the nginx container.
"docker ps" shows that the docker container is running. 
going to website.dev gives a 502 error. **This is unexpected.** I expect Nginx to now be able to connect to the now running docker container.

I reset the nginx server by running the following on the first docker-compose file:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Going to website.dev now displays the contents of the website container.

I make changes to the website container upload the new docker container to the private container. 
I use the following commands on the second docker-compose file:

```
docker-compose down
```

The old website container is no longer in existence.

```
docker-compose pull
```

The new website container is pulled.

```
docker-compose up
```

The new website container is now online.

Going to website.dev now displays the contents of the old (confirmed to be non-existent) container instead of the new container. **This is unexpected**

Reseting the nginx server will cause it to now deliver the correct website.

My question is, How do I configure nginx to just deliver whatever it finds at the configured url without having to reset the nginx server?

dockerfile as requested:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

COPY proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Comment: the website `command: npm run deploy` run a webserver or build static files ? can you provide Dockerfile for the webserver

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX Yes the server delivers static files. I edited the question to have the dockerfile.

Comment: So now, from NGinx (in container) point of view he can access to non shared files from another container ? your node deploy main juste compile file, so it's mean the result on the compiling must be shared with NGinx volumes somewhere

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. The website container hosts the files via http-server https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server. nginx should just deliver whatever that outputs on port 80 for that container. In my case, spinning down the website container and replacing it with a new website container with the same name makes nginx deliver content from the previous version of the endpoint.

The deploy script in package.json looks like this (it's an angular frontend)
"deploy": "ng build --prod && http-server ./dist/website -p 80"

Answer (score 0):

we got all the parameter.

Using angular-cli and compile the code with
`ng-build`, this result in a static files, you don't need to serve
them with proxy path. You only need to set the location to the folder
with `index.html` and everything will work alone without `http-server`

NGinx:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name website.dev _ default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.dev/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.dev/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        root /path/to/dist/website; # where ng build put index.html with all .js and assets
        index index.htm index.html;
    }
}
```

docker-compose NGinx:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  rproxy:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - '/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt'
      - '/host/path/shared:/path/to' # <-- Add this line. (host: /host/path/shared)
    networks:
      - main
networks:
  main:
    name: main_network
```

docker-compose website:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    website:
    image: registry.website.dev/frontendcontainer:latest
    command: npm run deploy
    volumes:
      - '/host/path/shared:/path/to' # <-- Add this line. (host: /host/path/shared)
    networks:
      main:
        aliases:
          - website
networks:
    main:
    external:
      name: main_network
```

Now `ng build --prod` will create index.html and assets into
`/host/path/shared/dist/website` (internally: `/path/to/dist/website`).

Then NGinx will have access to those file internally on
`/path/to/dist/website`, without using `http-server`. Angular is
frontend client it don't need to be start in production mode

Comment: Why does nginx need to have access to the files directly? Why can't it just deliver what it finds at the endpoint? This solution isn't general enough because it doesn't work if the server is instead a restful api backend.

Comment: To make it simple, if you want to serve "the static file" using node, so don't use NGinx. the first time the client will come, will download index.html from your http-server and then the front end will do his stuff without requestting again http-server, too much complexity to server one file, do it directly with NGinx. Touraren't deploy a backend App, but simply a static frontend index.html with dynamic content, sa don't interact with http-server